# How to get the opened popup?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm developing an MS Edge extension (using JavaScript), which periodically refreshes current window using the following call:

```
window.location.reload(1);
```

When, however, the page I'm currently on was opened as a result of a previous `POST` request, the refresh request opens below popup:

[image]

I'm not sure how I can handle this popup and automatically simulate the `Retry` click.

**UPDATE**

After struggling to find any info regarding this in different forums and documentation websites, I've decided to try to do the same in Google Chrome.
It took me only 4 hours to accomplish what I was looking for thanks to the great documentation and community support. I'm posting this update with an intention to close the question as it's not needed for me any more.

Comment: can you provide a sample code to produce the issue? We will try to make test with your code and try to find any solution or work around if any available.

Comment: later. Thanks @Deepak-MSFT. I've updated the post with some details to give better idea about how I actually do it. Please let me know if that's not enough, and I can share some more details.